# How can I make the Grub default options permanent

Tags: grub2

At the moment, I modify the file `/etc/default/grub` to set a specific option and then I run `sudo update-grub` in order to apply the change.

However, the file `/etc/default/grub` is often overwritten when I update my system and the grub package receives an update. Reading the documentation of grub2 it seems this file is meant for user settings, and then shouldn't be overwritten.

So, my question: how can I make a change permanent with Grub2 on Ubuntu when the `/etc/default/grub` file is overwritten with every update to the grub package ?

Thanks for your help.

note: I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04 but I had noticed this behavior in previous versions too.

Comment: At every update of the grub package you get the option to keep the configuration files.

Comment: Sure, however it's annoying to have to choose each time an update to the grub package takes place between replacing the file I use or keeping the old one with my values in it. If it's been updated, there must be a good reason, no ? Actually most of the time, no: it's just the exact original same file coming with the package and that overwrites my settings. To me, this looks like a defect because, according to the documentation of Grub, this file is meant to be modifiable by the users. Is there really no way to keep my settings when upgrading Grub ?